# Cannot install ADB for Kindle Fire HD

Tags: android, adb, device, kindle-fire

I'm trying to root it although after i install the correct ADB drivers, when I plug in my Kindle fire HD 7",

Kindle Fire
 -> Android Composite ADB Interface.

does not show up in device manager, hence I cannot preform the root.

I have added 0x1949 to the adb_usb.ini.

I have tried removing all drivers including the phatom ones restarting then reinstalling.

I have turn ADB in setting to on in the kindle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found for some devices that don't play nice the Universal driver from Koush does get them working - http://www.droid-life.com/2013/04/08/koush-releases-universal-adb-driver-for-windows/ but for the Kindle I've always had the KindleDrivers.exe from https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/connect-adb.html do the trick

Comment: Getting the driver direct from Amazon made it work flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This page...

https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/05-setting-up-your-kindle-fire-tablet-for-testing

...has instructions on how to get the driver (download the Amazon SDK) and install the driver as well as how to enable ADB on a Kindle Fire.

The page referenced above also has instructions on how to fix previous installation attempts that didn't work as you have described. 
This involves:

1. Deleting the default Portable Device driver on the PC
2. Installing the Kindle driver from the Amazon SDK
3. Updating the adb_usb.ini file (which can be done manually, or by installing the SDK)
4. Enabling ADB on the device
5. Plugging the device back in again

Answer (score 1):

I just did a follow up post with additional info on our official Amazon Developer Blog here:

http://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx3RZFBU0KJTSWS/Setting-up-the-ADB-driver-for-Kindle-Fire-Devices

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Dave