# Can't get ADB set up for Kindle Fire 2 (Otter2) - does not show as Android Composite ADB Interface

Tags: android, sdk, adb, drivers, kindle

Yes, I tried all the things from this one: [Cannot install ADB for Kindle Fire HD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256790/cannot-install-adb-for-kindle-fire-hd)

I have the 2012 Kindle Fire 7" (NOT HD, 2ND GEN - Otter2)

Trying to root, eventually install Cyanogen.

I have:

--Android SDK and adb running fine for other devices

--Windows host

I have tried:

--Uninstalling the drivers and reinstalling them, ensuring "Enable ADB" is selected in the Security menu

--drivers through the sdk manager, drivers direct from amazon, drivers randomly downloaded from all over the internet

--following various guides painstakingly (e.g. 
https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/05-setting-up-your-kindle-fire-tablet-for-testing or http://www.technipages.com/kindle-fire-enable-usb-debugging or http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2071010 or http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2069117)

--manually editing adb_usb.ini to include 0X1949 - except that by the time I tried this, it already included it

What I get, every time:

--Device Manager sees it as a "Portable Device" > "Kindle"

--I don't get "Android Composite ADB Interface" ever

--'adb devices' command doesn't see the Kindle

Help?

Comment: read http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Comment: Hi @AlexP. , I took a look at that and ran the commands but got no ouput - that bottom command states "cannot do anything on your PC side to make adb work until this command shows some output. If it shows nothing - the problem is not with your PC software configuration. It is with either your device software configuration or hardware (including PC, android device and everything in between - like USB cables, hubs, etc) " - but I got no output. Any suggestions on where it could be going wrong? I'm using a regular USB cable (also tried all these things with the stock cable).

Comment: Is USB debugging enabled? If yes, 1st try right-click it under Portable Devices and choose uninstall and see if it shows up under "Other Devices." Root guides should tell you where to go from there. Pls let me know.

Comment: Hi @sjoy, thanks for your comment, but no, it doesn't show up under "Other Devices" when I uninstall, it simply disappears. I've tried a few rounds of uninstall/reinstall including attempts with the kindle plugged in, not plugged in, with various drivers, etc. And yes, USB Debugging is enabled (via the "Enable ADB" setting - I never get to the stage where a popup asks me if I want to "allow usb debugging" like I get on my other devices).

Comment: Here is driver guide for 2013 model. Just follow steps for adb (not fastboot). Plug in with cable that came with device. Try some vanilla nexus driver (from the Universal list). Hope this helps https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_4My3JJRApsHv0PtdfGBslVWSSA43kO5RvYya96hyQg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Got a little farther but still stuck. By selecting "Update driver software" > "Browse" > "Let me pick" and then "adb interface" I now have Kindle Fire > Android ADB Interface listed in my Device Manager. However, it is still not recognized by "adb devices" command or any other attempt at testing the adb connection.

Comment: Which seems to put me at the same point as this person http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347561/adb-cannot-detect-my-kindle-fire-on-windows-7-but-device-manager-can but nothing from that thread worked. I have the adb_usb file in the right dir with the right contents and it's still not finding my device. I went ahead and tried the commands at @AlexP.'s link again but still no output.

Comment: If you use Win8+ there's deal you must go through for it to accept unsigned drivers. You will have to search. If Win7, you're opening CMD window from folder with adb.exe, yes? idk, but try this:  reboot computer and kindle. Do install driver steps again and try Google Nexus adb interface driver. Do steps to end (test adb devices). If doesn't work, try Google Galaxy Nexus drivers. Still no luck, maybe uninstall and start with clean slate. :\

Comment: gave up, got a fastboot cable, everything is peachy. If anyone else runs into this problem and is reading this, it's probably not worth your time to hope there's a fix. And don't try Tweezermod... you'll get a red-screened brick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, mostly note-to-self but just in case anyone else came across this... I was later able to switch this device from the deprecated CyanogenMod to Lineage OS by following this guide and starting straight at Step 6:
https://github.com/jsheradin/otter2_misc/blob/master/README.md
https://github.com/jsheradin/android_device_amazon_otter2/releases/latest

This time around, I never got adb devices to recognize the thing outside of twrp, but luckily I didn't need it outside of twrp.

And reminder, the end of the comment thread above and all related efforts ended here:
"gave up, got a fastboot cable, everything is peachy. If anyone else runs into this problem and is reading this, it's probably not worth your time to hope there's a fix. And don't try Tweezermod... you'll get a red-screened brick."
i.e. don't bother, just get the cable.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of different drivers and modifications to those drivers. It was eventually a driver installer I found [on Amazon's website](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/05-setting-up-your-kindle-fire-tablet-for-testing) that worked for me. I just installed it on top of my other Kindle Fire WinUsb driver installation.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/android-sdk-manager/redist/kindle_fire_usb_driver.zip

Below is my android_winusb.inf after the install.

```
;======= Kindle Fire WinUsb driver installation. =====================

[Version]
Signature           = "$Windows NT$"
Class               = KindleFireUsbDeviceClass
ClassGuid           = {6f75a202-3dc3-4dba-97bc-2af2832b5a73}
Provider            = %ManufacturerName%
DriverVer           = 10/27/2014,1.4.0000.00000
CatalogFile.NTx86   = kindlefirewinusbx86.cat
CatalogFile.NTamd64 = kindlefirewinusba64.cat

;======= Class section =================================================
[ClassInstall32]
Addreg = AndroidWinUsbClassReg


[AndroidWinUsbClassReg]
HKR,,,0,%ClassName%
HKR,,Icon,,-1

;========= Device section ==============================================
[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName% = Amazon, NTx86, NTamd64

[Amazon.NTx86]
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0006&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0008&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_000A&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0007&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_000B&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_000C&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_000D&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0800&MI_01

%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_00F0
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_00F2&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_00F4&MI_01

%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0120
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0122&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0124&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0012&MI_01

; For 64-bit os
[Amazon.NTamd64]
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0006&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0008&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_000A&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0007&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_000B&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_000C&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_000D&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0800&MI_01

%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_00F0
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_00F2&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_00F4&MI_01

%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0120
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0122&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0124&MI_01

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0012&MI_01
;======================================================================
[USB_Install]
Include = winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT

[USB_Install.Services]
Include     = winusb.inf
AddService  = WinUSB,0x00000002,WinUSB_ServiceInstall

[WinUSB_ServiceInstall]
DisplayName     = %WinUSB_SvcDesc%
ServiceType     = 1
StartType       = 3
ErrorControl    = 1
ServiceBinary   = %12%\WinUSB.sys

[USB_Install.Wdf]
KmdfService = WINUSB, WinUSB_Install

[WinUSB_Install]
KmdfLibraryVersion  = 1.9

[USB_Install.HW]
AddReg  = Dev_AddReg

[Dev_AddReg]
HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs,0x10000,"{F72FE0D4-CBCB-407d-8814-9ED673D0DD6B}"


[USB_Install.CoInstallers]
AddReg    = CoInstallers_AddReg
CopyFiles = CoInstallers_CopyFiles

[CoInstallers_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000,"WdfCoInstaller01009.dll,WdfCoInstaller","WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll"

[CoInstallers_CopyFiles]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll

[DestinationDirs]
CoInstallers_CopyFiles=11

;============== Source Media Section ================================================
[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\i386
2 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\amd64

[SourceDisksFiles.x86]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll  = 1
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll = 1

[SourceDisksFiles.amd64]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll  = 2
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll = 2


;======================= Strings ====================================================
[Strings]
ManufacturerName            = "Amazon.com"
CompositeAdbInterface       = "Android Composite ADB Interface"
SingleAdbInterface          = "Android ADB Interface"
SingleBootLoaderInterface   = "Android Bootloader Interface"
WinUSB_SvcDesc              = "Android USB Driver"
DISK_NAME                   = "Android WinUsb Installation Disk"
ClassName                   = "Kindle Fire"
```